# Missing cookies in Scrapy response

Tags: python, cookies, scrapy

When calling the following URL in Chrome:

> http://www.ooshop.com/courses-en-ligne/ContentNavigation.aspx?TO_NOEUD_IDMO=N000000013348&TO_NOEUD_IDFO=81285&NOEUD_NIVEAU=3

I got the following cookies:

```
LBcookie
OOshopSessionState
___utmvafIuiNzR
___utmvbfIuiNzR
___utmvmfIuiNzR
incap_ses_189_516467
visid_incap_516467
```

I am trying to retrieve them in `Scrapy`.
But when running it through `Scrapy` shell, I have only 4 out of 7 in `response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie')`.

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe there were redirects with cookie headers,  not just the last one

Answer (score 0):

- edit your settings.py
- add `COOKIES_DEBUG = True`